# Google App Engine modules + Task queue for iOS push notification

Tags: java, google-app-engine, push-notification, task-queue, app-engine-modules

I followed the instructions from [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java/tree/use_gae_modules) but it didn't work. The `frontend` added tasks to pull queue `notification-delivery` but iOS clients didn't receive any push notification. It seems that the `worker` didn't do its job. I don't know if the `worker` automatically scan the pull queue and send out the push (using Javapns) or not. And I don't know how to check if a task in a Pull queue is processed.

What I did:

1. Enable billing for GAE project.
2. Follow instructions from the sample (edit Constants, add p12 certificate).
3. `mvn clean install` from root directory.
4. `mvn clean package` from root directory.
5. `mvn appengine:update` from `cloudpush-ear` directory.
6. Make sure Javapns works with provided p12 file by writing some code in a standalone Java class, it did send push notifications to iOS clients.
7. When I call `PushNotificationWorkerServlet` by requesting from browser to `/_ah/start`, it throws an error saying `This feature is only available to backend instances.` So I tried using `ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest` instead of `ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread`. The error was gone but nothing happened.

I think GAE with Task Queue is a perfect solution for scalable mobile applications so I'll stick with it.

Any help please? Thank you.

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/ios-push-notifications/

Comment: Couldn't you add some logging into your task so you can see from the logs if it ran or not? In general though, a little more context wouldn't hurt here. Normally it is suggested that your question is self contained. If the sample disappears/gets updated, not much of your question is left. Do you mind adding the code you use to add the pull task, lease it, etc. Also including the queue.xml, and the code from the task itself, would be helpful